# Move some observation to different rows

Tags: r

e.g.

I have this data frame:

```
a 1 2 3 4 5 6
b 7 8 9 1 2 3
c 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and I want to transform it to:

```
a 1 2 3
a 4 5 6
b 7 8 9
b 1 2 3
c 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

Basically, for every single row, I want the e.g. 2nd to 6th, 7th to 11th, 11th to 15th... variable values to move a row below where the first variable value is the letter of the original row.

What should I do? I tried to work with gather() but that is not the case here.
I am just a beginner in R and would appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Can you specify the logic to transform

Comment: Do you need `rbind(df1[1:4], setNames(df1[c(1, 5:7)], names(df1)[1:4])) %>% arrange(1)`

Comment: Basically, for every single row, I want the e.g. 2nd to 6th, 7th to 11th, 11th to 15th... variable values to move a row below where the first variable value is the letter of the original row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This groups by 3 columns; just change the `%/% 3` to `%/% 5` for different numbers of columns. (This assumes that there are an equal number of columns in each grouping.)

```r
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split.default(dat[,-1], (seq_along(dat[,-1])-1) %/% 3), 
                             function(a) cbind(dat[,1,drop=FALSE], unname(a))))
out
#     V1 1 2 3
# 0.1  a 1 2 3
# 0.2  b 7 8 9
# 0.3  c 4 5 6
# 1.1  a 4 5 6
# 1.2  b 1 2 3
# 1.3  c 7 8 9
```

And we can clean it up a little with

```r
row.names(out) <- NULL
out[order(out[,1]),]
#   V1 1 2 3
# 1  a 1 2 3
# 4  a 4 5 6
# 2  b 7 8 9
# 5  b 1 2 3
# 3  c 4 5 6
# 6  c 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

### With `tidyverse`

#### Hard Code version

1. Isolate the first 4 columns (three values and the key) using `select`
2. `rbind` and `select` the last 3 columns and the key
3. EDIT Be sure to rename the columns that are to be combined with `rbind` to the same name as the select `df` from step 1 above.
4. `arrange` by the key

   ```
     df %>% 
      select(1:4) %>% 
      rbind(df %>% select(1, "v1" = 5,
                             "v2" = 6, 
                             "v3" = 7)) %>%
      arrange(key)



        #    key v1 v2 v3
        # 1   a  1  2  3
        # 2   a  4  5  6
        # 3   b  7  8  9
        # 4   b  1  2  3
        # 5   c  4  5  6
        # 6   c  7  8  9
   ```

## EDIT Generalized (a bit hairier)

sample df

```
   set.seed(42)
    df_2 <- tibble(
      bug = letters,
      col1 = sample(1:26),
      col2 = sample(1:26),
      col3 = sample(1:26),
      col4 = sample(1:26),
      col5 = sample(1:26),
      col6 = sample(1:26),
      col7 = sample(1:26),
      col8 = sample(1:26),
      col9 = sample(1:26),
      col10 = sample(1:26),
      col11 = sample(1:26),
      col12 = sample(1:26),
      col13 = sample(1:26),
      col14 = sample(1:26),
      col15 = sample(1:26)
    )
```

## A function that satisfies a generalized approach

```
   create_rowgroups.f <- function(df, key, groupsize){
  if( !(key %in% colnames(df)) ){
    print(paste(key, "is expected to be a column in df"))
    stop()
  }
  if( (ncol(df)-1) %% groupsize != 0 ){
    print("Function requires groups to fit all variable columns with the exception of the key")
    stop()
  }
  fnames = colnames(df[ , 1: (groupsize + 1) ])      
  df_2 <- bind_rows(lapply(
    1:(ncol(df)/groupsize),
    function(df, groupsize, key, fnames, index){
      pos1 = (index * groupsize) - groupsize + 2
      pos2 = (index * groupsize) + 1
      tempdf <- df %>% select(!!key, !!pos1:!!pos2)
      colnames(tempdf) = fnames
      return(tempdf)
    },
    df = df,
    key = key,
    fnames = fnames,
    groupsize = groupsize
  ))
  df_2 <- df_2 %>% arrange(across(.cols = key))
  return(df_2)
}
```

This is a lot of code that wraps around a simple line of `lapply` to assist the OP in using the UDF, `create_rowgroups.f`

Comment: In a comment, the OP stated that their real data should be segmented by every-5-columns. Can you *generalize* this so that you don't have to hard-code individual columns?

Comment: I can, let me get back into an R session.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the data showed is the one showed, this can be done by easy subsetting of columns, and `rbind` the datasets after setting the column names same

```
library(dplyr)
rbind(df1[1:4], setNames(df1[c(1, 5:7)], names(df1)[1:4])) %>% 
      arrange(1)
```

---

If there are many columns, an automatic method that is easier to understand would be `seq`.  Loop over the sequence of index, subset the columns, `rbind` within in `do.call` as we are creating a `list` by looping

```
out <- cbind(df1[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(2, ncol(df1), by = 3),
    function(i) setNames(df1[i:(i+2)], paste0("v", 2:4)))))
out[order(out$v1),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("a", "b", "c"), v2 = c(1L, 7L, 4L), v3 = c(2L, 
8L, 5L), v4 = c(3L, 9L, 6L), v5 = c(4L, 1L, 7L), v6 = c(5L, 2L, 
8L), v7 = c(6L, 3L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option

```
cbind(
  df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 2), ][1],
  do.call(
    "+",
    lapply(0:1,
      FUN = function(k) {
        kronecker(
          as.matrix(df[-1][(3*k-1)+2:4]),
          (matrix(c(1, 0), nrow = 2) + k) %% 2
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
```

such that

```
    V1 1 2 3
1    a 1 2 3
1.1  a 4 5 6
2    b 7 8 9
2.1  b 1 2 3
3    c 4 5 6
3.1  c 7 8 9
```